# Delphi: is it possibile in the OnFormShow event to tell a form not to display even for a millisecond?

Tags: delphi, tform

In the OnFormShow event I need (for a particular set of conditions) not to show the form.

Something like "if counter > 15 don't show the form".

I could of course refactor and move many things on form create, but this is a lot of work, because this is a common form and there are too many changes involved.

Now I close the form at the end of OnFormShow but anyway I see the form appear for some milliseconds.

Unfortunately the condition that tells me not to show the form is decided inside OnFormShow. Is there a trick to avoid the form to show?

Comment: May I suggest that you open the VCL source code and see how OnFormShow is invoked. It is not possible to change the visiblity of a form within OnFormShow events.  It is also not hard to avoid calling Show on things that you don't want shown.  If this is a common form and there are already too many changes involved, then what you are doing is adding technical debt 1 to technical debt 2.  Enjoy the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 on the refactoring, but in the mean time, try this:

AlphaBlend := true;

AlphaBlendValue := 0;

That should make the form invisible, and seemed to work in my OnShow test app (D2010/XP). I'm guessing you'll need to add code to make the form close, possibly a timer?

Comment: Might actually 'work', but I couldn't possibly upvote this trick! Sorry!

Comment: @Andreas And exactly how much dirtier is this trick compared to yours? ;)

Comment: Thanks, this trick worked for me. Clerarly refactoring is better, but I am close to a real life deadline and I want to minimize risks.

Comment: I also added Height := 0 and Width := 0 in addition to AlphaBlend (for cases like RDP where color depth is 8bit and effects like AlphaBlend are ignored).

Comment: @user193655: I think my solution is slightly better, since I imagine it will always work (and it does not rely on high-tech stuff like alpha blending).

Answer (score 9):

Refactor your code so that it doesn't show at all until you are ready. Either refrain from calling Show, or set Visible to False if you have not yet done so.

I suspect it's too late by the time you reach OnShow but even so doing it that way would be indicative of poor design. Moving code out of OnShow into a different method really should not be very much trouble at all.

Comment: yes I agree with you, but in this particular case there is nothing special, these are just "UI forms" (I mean some simple "navigation" forms, with some logic in it, nothin linked to DB, very simple stuff that doesn't need killer design), nothing incredible, and if a trick I avoid that flickering it would be better. I mean of course I can refactor, but in the same time I can develop a new feature. So the Cost/Benefits ratio of this refactoring is very low for me. So do you confirm there is no trick at all?

Comment: I can't confirm anything since I've no Delphi at the moment. You can though. Call Abort in the OnShow handler and see if the form appears at all. I bet it still appears. Even so, I'd be very suspicious of calling Abort in OnShow production code. Really, just refactor!

Answer (score 4):

A very bad solution is to do

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(n);
  if n > 15 then
  begin
    Left := Screen.DesktopWidth + 32;
    Top := Screen.DesktopHeight + 32;
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  end;
end;
```